# Формирование римских цифр

Tags: prolog

Здравствуйте. Такая проблема на прологе возникла, помогите, подскажите) В данном коде например 9 записывается в виде VIIII, а не IX. Как-то можно это исправить, не добавляя факт(9,IX)?

```
predicates
nondeterm figure(integer,string)
араб_рим(integer,string)

clauses        
араб_рим(0,""):-!.
араб_рим(A,R):-figure(A1,R1),  
        A2 = A-A1, A2>=0,!,
        араб_рим(A2,R2),
        concat(R1,R2,R).         
figure(1000, "M"). 
figure(500, "D"). 
figure(100, "C"). 
figure(50, "L"). 
figure(10, "X"). 
figure(5, "V"). 
figure(1, "I").
goal    
араб_рим(9,R).
```

Comment: Думаю, нужно сначала пробовать вычитать 1/100/1000, а потом уже пробовать их добавлять.

Comment: Там нет правил для 4, 40, 400. Они формируются иначе, т.е. сначал I (для 4), потом V. И т.д. Точно такая же канитель с 9, 90, 900.

Comment: @alexlz, а можете как-то пример в виде кода написать?

Comment: @wicS Нет. Но вот гугл по запросу даёт кучу ссылок. Среди них http://www.dailyfreecode.com/code/prolog-convert-decimal-number-roman-3034.aspx и https://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/341/03sp/slides/PrologEx/roman.pl.html